# Assign listbox selecteditem to button_click

Tags: c#, listbox

Can anyone help me with this? I am creating several of listboxes, gridviews and buttons dynamically when my page is loading and I need to know how I can pass the selected item of a listbox to the button click? This is my code:

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=N/A;Initial Catalog=GB_COCKPIT;Integrated Security=True");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand SelectServeur = new SqlCommand("SELECT  NomServeur, palier, description, responsable FROM pltf_Web.[GBV1001_Inventaire_IIS_Complet] where[FONCTION DE BASE] = 'NON CLASSÉ' AND[Fonction Caracteristique etendue] IS NULL", con);
    SqlCommand SelectNomServeur = new SqlCommand("SELECT  NomServeur FROM pltf_Web.[GBV1001_Inventaire_IIS_Complet] where[FONCTION DE BASE] = 'NON CLASSÉ' AND[Fonction Caracteristique etendue] IS NULL", con);

    SqlDataReader dr = SelectServeur.ExecuteReader();
    dt.Load(dr);
    SqlDataReader dr1 = SelectNomServeur.ExecuteReader();
    dt1.Load(dr1);

    var NBServeurs = dt.Rows.Count;

    for (int i = 0; i < NBServeurs; i++)
    {
        var nomserveurs = dt1.Rows[i].ItemArray;
        var NomServeur = nomserveurs[0];
        SqlCommand SelectComposantes = new SqlCommand("SELECT b.ID_Composant as composante  FROM[gb_cockpIT].[pltf_web].[GBV1001_Inventaire_IIS_Complet] as a inner join[dbo].[GBD0007_Liste_Composant] as b on a.[Composante de base] = b.Nom_Composant_FR where a.NomServeur ='" + NomServeur + "'  and b.ID_Plateforme = 103", con);
        SqlDataReader dr2 = SelectComposantes.ExecuteReader();
        dt2.Load(dr2);

        DataTable dt4 = new DataTable();
        SqlCommand SelectServeurs = new SqlCommand("SELECT  NomServeur, palier, [composante de base],description, responsable FROM pltf_Web.[GBV1001_Inventaire_IIS_Complet] where[FONCTION DE BASE] = 'NON CLASSÉ' AND[Fonction Caracteristique etendue] IS NULL and  NomServeur ='" + NomServeur + "'", con);
        SqlDataReader dr4 = SelectServeurs.ExecuteReader();
        dt4.Load(dr4);

        GridView NomGridView = new GridView();
        NomGridView.ID = "GridView" + i.ToString();
        NomGridView.Width = 900;
        NomGridView.DataSource = dt4;
        NomGridView.DataBind();
        form1.Controls.Add(NomGridView);
        form1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));

        DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
        var nomComposantes = dt2.Rows[i].ItemArray;
        var nomComposante = nomComposantes[0];
        SqlCommand GetListComposantes = new SqlCommand("DECLARE @return_value int EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[GBSP0004_Liste_Fonctions]  @IDComposant = " + nomComposante + "", con);
        SqlDataReader dr3 = GetListComposantes.ExecuteReader();
        dt3.Load(dr3);

        ListBox NomListBox = new ListBox();
        NomListBox.DataValueField = dt3.Columns["code_fonction"].ToString();
        NomListBox.ID = "ListBox" + i.ToString();
        NomListBox.DataSource = dt3;
        NomListBox.DataBind();
        NomListBox.Height = 200;

        form1.Controls.Add(NomListBox);
        form1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
        form1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));

        Button NouveauBouton = new Button();
        NouveauBouton.ID = "Bouton" + i.ToString();
        NouveauBouton.Text = "Assigner";
        form1.Controls.Add(NouveauBouton);

        NouveauBouton.Click += new EventHandler(this.button_Click);

        form1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
        form1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
        form1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<hr>"));
        form1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
        form1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));

    }
    con.Close();
}

protected void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button buttonID = sender as Button;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you're iterating and generating controls. If I understood correctly you can let the button to know what is the related ListBox. Then, on click, you get the list box and see what is selected.

First you need to add this code line: `NouveauBouton.Attributes["ListBox"] = NomListBox.ID;`.

So in your Page_Load you have:

```
Button NouveauBouton = new Button();
NouveauBouton.ID = "Bouton" + i.ToString();
NouveauBouton.Text = "Assigner";
form1.Controls.Add(NouveauBouton);
NouveauBouton.Attributes["ListBox"] = NomListBox.ID;
NouveauBouton.Click += new EventHandler(this.button_Click);
```

In your handler:

```
protected void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button)sender;
    if (button.Attributes["ListBox"] != null)
    {
        ListBox listBox = (ListBox)this.FindControl(button.Attributes["ListBox"]);
        string selected = listBox.SelectedValue;
        //do stuff
    }
}
```